# .click() not working when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have a normal js script which has been working since the start of my project. But now for some reason when I click on buttons nothing works at all, no response from the clicking event(note this used to work) and nothing displays in the console log stating if there is an error of some sort... the script just doesn't respond...

Here is the HTML:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/myscript.js"></script>

<form>
   <input type="text" name="signinemail" id="signinemail" placeholder="Enter Email">
   <input type="password" name="signinpassword" id="signinpassword" placeholder="Enter Password">
   <input type="submit" id ="siginsubmit" name="siginsubmit" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

Here is my javascript:

```js
$(document).on('pageinit',"#sellbookpage",
    function()
    {
        $("#siginsubmit").click
            (
                function()
                {
                   alert("hello");
                }   
            );
    }
);
```

Note I am making use of jQuery Mobile

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(document).on('pageinit', function() {...});`? Why are you passing the selector in the second parameter?

Comment: @nnnnnn See [these docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handlereventObject).

Comment: @ajp15243 - Yes, I'm familiar with the `.on()` method. I was questioning the use of a delegated `'pageinit'` event.

Comment: @nnnnnn Ah I see what you mean now, carry on then.

Comment: agreed to  nnnnnn. It seems to me that the selector you passed to the on event is causing the problem. It would be helpful if you also provide the html that contains that selector.

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob here by selector you mean sellbookpage?? or the buttons id?

Comment: It seems that all the script works fine just ALL the .click() methods don't run at all, so I'm not sure what causes this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The winning answer to my problem was nothing to do with any of the above posts mentioned above! What was causing the problem was I was using the jQuery mobile, jQuery and Twitter Bootstrap. As soon as I commented out the link to the bootstrap css everything started to work as it used to. Thus there must be a conflict between Twitters Bootstrap and either jQuery or jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

The `pageinit` event is only available if you use jQuery Mobile. Are you still using that? Otherwise you should use `$(document).ready( ... )`.

Comment: Ya sorry to mention that, I'm using the jquery Mobile as I'm making a phonegap app

Answer (score 0):

have u tried using *live()*

```js
$("#sellbookpage").live('pageinit', function() {
            $("#siginsubmit").click(function(){
                 alert("hello");
            });
});
```

Comment: Just tried the code above and still nothing, does anyone have suggestions of some debugging techniques to help try find the error?

Comment: If you use Firebug or another debugger, set a breakpoint inside the ``pageinit`` handler to check that your click handler is being set up.

Comment: try wrapping my above code inside `$(function() {  //code here; });` which will stop it from loading until document is ready

Comment: Unless you're using a version of jQuery below 1.7, you should *not* use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), as it is deprecated. You're supposed to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead (which was introduced in jQuery 1.7).

Comment: Further to what @ajp15243 said, you shouldn't use `.live()` unless using a version older than 1.4.3 (because from that version on you should use `.delegate()`; from 1.7 on you should use `.on()`).

Answer (score 0):

From http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handlereventObject:

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.

`siginsubmit` is an `input` (which cannot contain descendant elements let alone descendant elements with `id="sellbookpage"`) so the selector string is not matching anything and the click event is never reaching the `siginsubmit` input.

Change it to this:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
    $('#siginsubmit').click(function (e) {
        alert('hello');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VG3Eg/

Comment: I've copy pasted your code into my project and made sure that I commented all other occurrences of signinsubmit and still nothing... It just doesn't fire that .click() method at all... Sigh... Note this was your working code from jsfiddle. Thanks a million for the help though